# Scrapy Pagination follow upto 2 pages but it has to follow more

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Pagination got results of page_1 and page_2 while it has to follow more than that i.e upto 10 pages. I change next_page .ccs selector with .xpath but nothing work for me.

```
class YellSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yell'
    base_url = 'https://www.yell.com{}'
    start_urls = ['https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?scrambleSeed=770796459&keywords=hospitals&location=united+kingdom']

    def parse(self, response):
        for data in response.css('div.row.businessCapsule--mainRow'):
            title = data.css('.text-h2::text').get()
            avg_rating = response.css('span.starRating--average::text').get()
            business_url = data.css('a.businessCapsule--title::attr(href)').get()
            final_url = self.base_url.format(business_url)

            yield scrapy.Request(final_url,callback=self.parse_site,cb_kwargs={"title":title,"avg_rating":avg_rating})

        next_page = response.urljoin(response.css('a.pagination--next::attr(href)').extract_first())
        if next_page is not None:
           yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_site(self,response,title,avg_rating):
        opening_hours  = response.css('strong::text').get()
        opening_hours = opening_hours.strip() if opening_hours else ""

        items = {
            'Title': title,
            'Average Rating': avg_rating,
            'Hours': opening_hours
        }
        yield items
```

Comment: Indentation of `next_page` line and onward should be outside of `for loop` block within `parse` method.

Comment: i already did that and get results only upto page 1

Comment: Your code should not run at all. There are few things missing in there. Where did you find this `final_url`? You should also use `=` after `cb_kwargs`.

Comment: i corrected that mistake cb_kwargs={...} and final_url is the link of that title that will give us Hours data

Answer (score 0):

I ran the script right now and found that it is doing fine. If you see that the script is grabbing the content from first page only, you surely wanna check out [this link](https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?scrambleSeed=770796459&keywords=hospitals&location=united+kingdom) manually to be sure whether you have been rate limited. When you visit the page manually and see the captcha page, make sure to take half-an-hour break and then run the script again.

```
class YellSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yell'
    base_url = 'https://www.yell.com{}'
    start_urls = ['https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?scrambleSeed=770796459&keywords=hospitals&location=united+kingdom']

    def parse(self, response):
        for data in response.css('div.row.businessCapsule--mainRow'):
            title = data.css('.text-h2::text').get()
            avg_rating = response.css('span.starRating--average::text').get()
            business_url = data.css('a.businessCapsule--title::attr(href)').get()
            final_url = self.base_url.format(business_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(final_url,callback=self.parse_site,cb_kwargs={"title":title,"avg_rating":avg_rating})

        next_page = response.css('a.pagination--next::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_site(self,response,title,avg_rating):
        opening_hours  = response.css('strong::text').get()
        opening_hours = opening_hours.strip() if opening_hours else ""

        items = {
            'Title': title,
            'Average Rating': avg_rating,
            'Hours': opening_hours
        }
        yield items
```

Comment: Yes you were right, script is grabbing the content from first page only but when i run a simple script exactly same as above with the same "start_url" it will give me all the content from all the pages and i don't have to do any manually work. Below is the simple code of yell